# eclipse has bugs with showing code complementation and the cursor

Tags: linux, eclipse, archlinux, eclipse-jdt, efxclipse

Heys guys,

I just installed eclipse with e(fx)clipse and got some problems with the exspecially the layout. First of all the cursor does not being visually updated when doing horizontally movements(vertically works just fine). But this is only visually, when I edit the code it is on the correct position.

Aswell I have to click on the error warning at the line numbers to get the code complementation window longer then about 0.1 seconds. But even the it only shows up in the left top corner.

At last I have to close eclipse in the console or it will just freeze.

OS: Arch Linux always updated,

Eclipse: Version 4.5.1, java version,

Java: java-8-openjdk

Installed plugins: e(fx)clipse.

Hope you guys can help me,
Armin

Comment: OpenJDK is not a supported environment, neither is Arch: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_5.xml#target_environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys,

I figured out the solution for myself. The problem is GTK. With disabling it all the problem were solved. To do this start eclipse with the command line:

```
SWT_GTK3=0 eclipse
```

Sadly I have not yet found out how to do this permanently, but I will edit this answer as soon as I find out.

Armin